# Jquery fadeout of item, item doesn't reappear

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, iframe

I have my main page that contains a DIV that in turn contains an IFRAME. When the user clicks the OK button in the IFRAME, I call a function in the parent page that fades out the div with a Jquery fadeOut command. When I try to make the DIV fade in once again, it doesn't. What am I doing wrong?

**MAIN PHP PAGE:**

```
<div id="regcontainer">
    <iframe id="registration" src="register.html" frameborder="0" allowtransparency="true" scrolling="auto"></iframe>
</div>
```

**JQUERY COMMAND IN JS FILE INCLUDED IN THE MAIN PAGE, THAT FADES OUT THE DIV:**

```
var closeIFrame = function() { 
    $('#regcontainer').fadeOut("fast"); 
}
```

**Fade In:**

```
$('#register').click(function() { $('#regcontainer').fadeIn("fast"); });
```

Comment: Not showing what exactly you're doing to fade-in the div.

Comment: .....is there any code to make it fade back in again? You could try `.fadeToggle("fast")` if you want that behaviour

Comment: Please provide jsFiddle if possible, as your code is incomplete

Answer (score 0):

You must use the fadeIn method. http://api.jquery.com/fadeIn/

```
var showIFrame = function() {
    $('#regcontainer').fadeIn("fast");
}
```

Comment: This is my fadeIn code:

 $('#register').click(function() {
  $('#regcontainer').fadeIn("fast");
 });
Only the DIV (#regcontainer) fades back in, but the iframe doesn't reappear.

Comment: @user2729463 - please add that to your question.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `fadeToggle()` to make your `div` toggle its state. Also I think you can use `fadeIn()` too, but since you want to make make your div appear and disappear simultaneously, `fadeToggle()` is the best choice.

http://api.jquery.com/category/effects/fading/ this should provide all information you need

Comment: I started out with toggle, but it had the same effect. Only the DIV returns, not the iFrame.

Comment: Just a wild guess, perhaps the `allowtransparency` attribute might be causing some trouble.

Comment: Tried it just now. Still no change.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this, here's a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mdesdev/pKpUV/)

```
<a href="#" class="register-open">Register</a>

<div id="regcontainer">
  <iframe id="registration" src="http://fiddle.jshell.net/user/login/" frameborder="0" allowtransparency="true" scrolling="auto">
  </iframe>
  <a href="#" class="register-close">Close</a>
</div>


$(function() {

  $('.register-open').click(function() {
    $('#regcontainer').slideToggle(450);
  });
  $('.register-close').click(function() {
    $('#regcontainer').slideToggle(450 ); 
  });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't use fadeToggle() if the OK button is inside the div that's fading out, since you can't press it afterwards.

I believe you're looking for something like this:

HTML

```
<div id="regcontainer">
    <div class="button"></div>
</div>
<div class="button2"></div>
```

jQuery

```
$('.button').on('click', function() {
  $('#regcontainer').fadeOut('fast');
})

$('.button2').on('click', function() {
  $('#regcontainer').fadeIn('fast');
})
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Sb9BG/)

Comment: In your example, you created and managed the CLOSE button outside of the HTML page you loaded inside the iframe. This makes the CLOSE button unmanageable since doesn't scroll along with the laoded page. In my case, the jquery to close the loaded page is found WITHIN that page and not outside. Everything else is pretty much the same as in your example, but when I try to show the page again, only the iframe shows up, not the contents. It's like the external HTML page never gets loaded.